# The method .map in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<<>> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: t-sql, bigdata, apache-spark-sql, rdd, talend

I am getting an error in talend. PFA.
[image]

Please find more details of the mapping.

[image]

Can you please help me here?.

Thank You
Tom

Comment: Hi Tom. Could you please share the component settings view of your component ?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with code generation of Talend Bigdata version.
There were 5 subjobs in my job. 
I was testing the functionality of last three subjobs.(Off late i have added 3 extra tSql components into my 4th subjob , which you can see in the screenshot).
For that i have de-activated the first two subjobs.(I have de-activated the first two subjobs earlier as well and unit tested which was fine)

I assumed this was the issue with code generation of talend.
(Earlier also I faced similar issue with .map() function of tSql component. That time i deleted tSql component and created it again and issue went away.)

I proceeded with the following trial and error method.

- I closed the job and reopened again ( issue exists)
- I restarted Talend tool and reopened again (issue exists)
- I deleted the tSql components and created them again (issue exists)
- I activated the de-activated subjobs and then checked again(ISSUE DISAPPEARED)